# Continous random variable short proof

Tags: distributions, random-variable

I am given the problem:

If X is a continuous random variable with cumulative distribution function F and density function f, show that the random variable Y = X^2 is also continuous and express its cumulative distribution function in terms of F and f.

Isn't a continuous random variable multiplied by itself also a continuous random variable? If so, can't we just say Y = F^2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s again continuous since its support is all non-negative numbers. But, CDF is wrong. We deal with transformations as follows in general:

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\leq y)=P(X^2\leq y)=P(\sqrt{y}\geq X\geq -\sqrt{y})=F_X(\sqrt{y})-F_X(-\sqrt{y})$$ when $y\geq 0$. If you want pdf of Y, just take the derivative of this.

Comment: Shouldn't the last part of the expression be -Fx(sqrt(y)), not -Fx(-sqrt(y))?

Comment: Also apologies for the syntax, I am new here and I don't know how to use the mathematical syntax in my posts in the comments.

Comment: You need to subtract $P(X < a)$ from $P(X < b) $ to get $P(a < X < b)$. (Ignoring equalities because of continuity)

Comment: Ah, thank you for the reminder. As for the pdf I believe it would be $\frac {1}{2}fx(\frac {1}{2\sqrt{y}}) - \frac {1}{2}fx(\frac {-1}{2\sqrt{y}})$

Comment: @CrystalMcMillian derivative of $\sqrt{y}$ goes out of $f$. Review the chain rule.

Comment: I think this answer is seriously flawed, because you have adopted an unusual interpretation of "continuous." Consider, for instance, a 50-50 mixture of a Normal and Gamma variable: the support is "all positive numbers" but it's manifestly *not* continuous in any ordinary sense of the word.